# mvc model validation required not working on all fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have the problem that my model validation isn't working correctly. For some reason not all my required fields have to be filled in.

Here's my model:

```
public class MovieModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RoleInMovie> RoleInMovie { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Name:</label></td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Genre:</label></td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Genre)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genre)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Price:</label></td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

And here's my action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(MovieModel model)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Now here's the thing: as soon as I enter only a price, modelstate.isvalid becomes true. When hovering over my model, it sais both name and genre are null. Ofcourse they are required, but the validation doesn't work.
Also, the validationmessagefor only works on price.

I hope I'm not overlooking something too ridiculous. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what happens when you click submit?

Comment: If I fill in a price, modelstate becomes valid and I go to index. If I didn't fill in the price, I go to return View(); and only price gives an error. Name and Genre NEVER give errors or make modelstate not valid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Return the invalid model back to the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(MovieModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model); // <----
}
```

Oh, and make sure that the required attribute is disallowing empty strings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings.aspx

```
public class MovieModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoleInMovie> RoleInMovie { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This did not work however. Only price is getting checked as always.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol AllowEmptyStrings is the error I'm currently getting. My Resharper isn't pointing me to any missed references or is he overlooking something?

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens What version of MVC? If it's 1 or 2 you might have to write a custom validation attribute for this.

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens It should be there then, it's part of the .net runtime and is not MVC specific.  Did you include `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` ?

Comment: That was not included. I have included it now. Apparently my resharper added microshoft.build.framework, which also supports [required], but conflicts with dataannotations. Thank you for the help here, you saved my day. It works the way it should right now.

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens You're welcome, I've run into this same problem in the past.