# Some Required fields not working on ViewModel MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

Controller Action:

```
 [AjaxRequestOnly, HttpPost, Authorize]
    public ActionResult AddCreditCard(CustomerCreditCardModelView cc) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return Content(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e=>e.ErrorMessage)));
        }
        // .... do something ...        
    }
```

ModelView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CheckoutVC.CheckoutServiceReference;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class CustomerCreditCardModelView {

    [Display(Name = "Número")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Número es requerido")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 12, ErrorMessage = "El número parece ser incorrecto")]
    [JsonIgnore, ScriptIgnore]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Código de seguridad")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Código de seguridad es requerido")]
    public string CardSecurityCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre en la tarjeta")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre en la tarjeta es requerido")]
    public string NameOnCard { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dirección de cobro")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Dirección de cobro es requerida")]
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mes de vencimiento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Mes de vencimiento es requerido")]
    public int ExpirationMonth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Año de vencimiento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Año de vencimiento es requerido")]
    public int ExpirationYear { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Documento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El documento es requerido")]
    public string Document { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de tarjeta")]
    public int IdCreditCard { get; set; }

    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int IdCustomerCreditCard { get; set; }
    public CustomerCreditCardModelView() {

    }
```

Request Payload:

```
{"idCreditCard":1,"nameOnCard":"fdsa","billingAddress":"fdsa"}
```

Request Response:

```
["El Número es requerido","El Código de seguridad es requerido","El documento es requerido"]
```

As you can see, everything works perfectly except that int ExpirationMonth and int ExpirationYear should return a validation error (required) but they doesnt.

Actually, modelstate have only 6 keys....

What can be causing this behaviour? I want to expirationMonth and expirationYear takes into consideration the [Required] DataAnnotation attribute.

Pretty sure is the same happening here: [mvc model validation required not working on all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359334/mvc-model-validation-required-not-working-on-all-fields)

EDIT: Reading the comments on that question see that the problem was the using, not my case tho. I included the using part.

Comment: Is some of the content hidden on the screen when you try to validate?

Comment: server side validation is not working.

Comment: if I add in the request payload something like expirationMonth: null, the data annotation works. This is insane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because `ExpirationMonth` and `ExpirationYear` properties are integer values. Integer is value type so it cannot be null, the default value will be 0 which is correct from the RequiredAttribute's point of view.

What you can do is to change the type from `int` to `int?` so it can be null.

See [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Your viewmodel:

```
public class CustomerCreditCardModelView {

    [Display(Name = "Número")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Número es requerido")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 12, ErrorMessage = "El número parece ser incorrecto")]
    [JsonIgnore, ScriptIgnore]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Código de seguridad")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Código de seguridad es requerido")]
    public string CardSecurityCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre en la tarjeta")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre en la tarjeta es requerido")]
    public string NameOnCard { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dirección de cobro")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Dirección de cobro es requerida")]
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mes de vencimiento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Mes de vencimiento es requerido")]
    public int? ExpirationMonth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Año de vencimiento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Año de vencimiento es requerido")]
    public int? ExpirationYear { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Documento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El documento es requerido")]
    public string Document { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de tarjeta")]
    public int IdCreditCard { get; set; }

    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int IdCustomerCreditCard { get; set; }
    public CustomerCreditCardModelView() {

    }
}
```

**Another approach** is to make the validation more strict, from the names `ExpirationMonth` and `ExpirationYear` I think the [RangeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx)  is appropriate for you.

Comment: they are int for a reason, i want to have an invalid validation if i don't send in the request. This ain't the problem. Actually the problem lies in that server side validation accept input even with those values not defined.

Comment: This is the problem. 0 is a valid integer. Model validation is there to validate the model. It has nothing to do with the request, that's a different responsibility. int? (which is Nullable<int>) will be null when the ModelBinder creates the object based on the request (if the request doesn't contain any information for that property).

Comment: Ok, so serverside validation on an int required doesn't even check if the model receive the int value. So you can easily pass model validation with a fiddler ... sounds kinda awful design.

Comment: Ok experimenting a bit, i found out how it works and looks like the model binder do a new object (with default values of course) before testing against any dataannotation from the request. I understand why it does that, still doesn't look quite good to me and a little counter intuitive. Still think it's awful that you cannot do a data annotation required for an int, huge security flaw to my eyes.

Comment: Another weird issue... If i set : 
[Range(2012,2020,ErrorMessage="El Año de vencimiento parece ser incorrecto.")]
        public int ExpirationYear { get; set; }

and i don't explicitly set an expirationYear the error message is the default : The Año de vencimiento field is required. should I file a bug/concern somewhere?

Comment: I'm sure it behaves like that for a reason, but if you feel it's a bug you can open up a thread here: http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx

Comment: Love you man! Your answer resolve my "bug" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710919/mvc-4-range-validator-not-accepting-minimum-value