# MVC 4 Range validator not accepting minimum value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to use Range Validator in my asp.net mvc 4 project. In view model I added:

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The Region field is required.")]
public int Region { get; set; }
```

And in controller i checked it by `ModelState.IsValid`.

The problem is ModelState don't accept `0` as a properly value - it's strange because I set range **from** `0` to `max int`, so I thought that `0` belong to collection (like in MVC 5 if I remember). Am I wrong or it's just a bug? Any others value is reading properly (`-1` is not accepting and `1001` is ok).

**UPDATE 1**

[image: Debug 1]
[image]

(Like you see in above pictures I don't anything with my model before I not check if model is valid).

Register method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //I was never here! Always ModelState.IsValid returns false
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ViewBag.Regions = _database.Department.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Full RegisterViewModel class:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public int Role { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The Region field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Region")]
    public int Region { get; set; }
}
```

Register view:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role)
                <select id="Role" name="Role" data-val-required="The Role field is required." data-val="true">
                    <option value="">Choose role for user</option>
                    <option value="1">Administrator</option>
                    <option value="2">Inspector</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li id="region-section">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Region)
                <select id="Region" name="Region" data-val-required="The Region field is required." data-val="true">
                    <option value="" selected>Choose region</option>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Regions)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
```

**UPDATE 2**

According to @pilotcam advice I have used `ValidateModel()` function. In debug mode I got HResult: `-2146233079` - I was trying convert it into System Error Code (`-2146233079 & 0xFFFF = 5385`) but is not a part of [System Error Codes list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This should not happen. Did you debug and see nothing else is going wrong?

Comment: @ArghyaC: yes, I was debug and ModelState.IsValid had false only in Region key. Rest keys of my RegisterViewModel had true.

Comment: In `RangeAttribute`, both min & max values are included. I just checked the source code as well. They are fine. See if something else is changing the values, or there are some other mistakes, if any.

Comment: Perhaps try adding more content/code to your question.  Seems like something else is going on here.  Any custom binders for example?  What is the value of `Region` when you are stopped in debug mode?  What if you run `ModelState.Clear(); ValidateModel(model);`

Comment: @ArghyaC: I don't do anything with model until I not check if is valid. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I've found answer. The problem was in type of my field (`public int Region { get; set; }`). If I don't set anything, mvc trying set null to `Region` but *int* isn't nullable so in controller during debugging I still getting `0` instead `null` which was ambiguous.

I didn't have `[Required]` attribute, but not-nullable type added it automatically (with error name "The X field is required" ... yeah, just like my custom error message in `[Range]` attribute).

The solution is change:

```
public int Region { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public int? Region { get; set; }
```

... in viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks, I know you got negative points on your initial question but that null validates to false when the model hasn't been populated wasn't obvious except in retrospect.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using ViewBag, I would suggest adding a Regions property to your Register class, like so:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    // ... existing code

    public SelectList Regions { get; set; }
}
```

This requires some updates to your action methods:

```
// your GET action
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var model = new RegisterModel();
    model.Regions = new SelectList(_database.Department, "Id", "Name", model.Region);

    return View(model);
}
```

And then, finally, update your view:

```
<li id="region-section">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Region)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Region, Model.Regions, "Select one...")
</li>
```

This seems to be more consistent than using ViewBag and writing the `<select>` element by hand, in my experience.

If you still are getting odd results from validation, I'd recommend installing [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/#download) and checking out the [model binding tab](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Model-Binding-Tab), which will show how your posted values are being mapped.